# What's the full frame equvialance of this phone lens?

Tags: focal-length

I took a photo with my phone, and here is the EXIF:

```
F/2 4mm 1/14s ISO-1250
```

I searched on the Internet and found that the sensor is Sony IMX134, 1/4 inch. Then how to calculate the equivalent focal length of this lens?

(The equivalent focal lens of an APS-C lens is about 1.5 of the focal length. For example, a 35mm lens is equivalent to 52.5mm full frame.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crop-factor [is specified](http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/f5952a21) as 9.42.

So you have a 4 x 9.42 = 38mm equivalent lens.

Apparently, that "Type 1/4 sensor" has to be taken with a grain of salt. 
The diagonal seems to be 0.18", closer to 1/5.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! According to your figure, I guess I can take this lens as a standard prime (about 50mm).

Comment: It's a little wider than standard, the usual range for that is 43-50 mm. But yes, it's close and less wide than most phonecams that I'm aware of.